# Assign arbitrary directory to a package in Maven/Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, build

I'm working on the project that has unusual structure. It's not built by build system but by IntelliJ IDEA IDE. I know, such approach is poor and fragile in general. But I have to live with that.

Key feature of IDEA is an ability to assign arbitrary package to a directory. And the project I'm working on relies on this feature heavily (the project is very complex and ancient).

I created simplified project just for illustration. For example, it's possible to keep two directories `reports` and `database` belonging to `com.mycompany.internal` package and assign `com.mycompany.external` package to `rest` directory:

[image: Project structure in IDEA]

While on the disk the structure is the following:

```
└───src
    ├───database
    ├───reports
    └───rest
```

As far as I know, build systems like Maven and Gradle can handle multiple source roots. For example, in Gradle it's possible to specify several directories:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src'
            srcDirs 'src1'
            srcDirs 'src2'
        }
    }
 }
```

But inside `src` Gradle expects the following hierarchy (according to Java packages):

```
└───src
    └───com
        └───mycompany
            ├───internal
            └───external
```

Seems that there is no way to alter such a behavior of Maven/Gradle out-of-the-box... Well, I can use Ant as alternative (it's quite flexible) but such approach will be too imperative and tedious. Or I need to write new plugin for Maven/Gradle that will generate IDEA project files?

Comment: [This user](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188855) seems to use some way to make it work in Gradle and IntelliJ IDEA can also import the settings from [Gradle configuration](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/wiki/DSL-spec-v.-0.5#package-prefix-requires-idea-20191) since 2019.1.

Comment: I would recommend to change your structure and follow conventions over configuration paradigm.

Answer (score 2):

The Java compiler literally does not care about sources being located in folders matching their package name(s).

So the only thing you need to do in Gradle is properly configure the source directories, with something like:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs "src/database", "src/reports", "src/rest"
        }
    }
}
```

And then follow the [IntelliJ documentation](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/wiki/DSL-spec-v.-0.5#package-prefix-requires-idea-20191) for making the import work.